# Вставка видео с ютуба через iframe

Tags: youtube

На сайт вставил видео-обзор организации через iframe.
При загрузке страницы происходит запрос лого https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/APkrFKaSxaTL_lYRjOCX9W-Y9JHkl-edJOZF2aMlcRDo=s68-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj, что приводит у увеличению загрузки страницы до 30 секунд.
запрос завершается ошибкой.
Могу ли я как то запретить делать данный запрос? Или есть какое то иной решение? Попробовал загрузить видео на рутуб, так там в начале реклама показывается(( Не хочу хранить видео в проекте и вставлять либу с плеером сторонним.